# OpenShift Play Application Deployment websocket

Tags: openshift, playframework-2.3

Hello  I have finished the tutorial here https://github.com/JamesSullivan/play2-openshift-quickstart and my application is up and running on Openshift.

However, the application uses websockets. Websockets are not working. I have tried many browsers as well. I have searched everywhere and found one response telling people to port to 8080. I have done this.

Can I have some suggestions or maybe links to source that has working websockets on Openshift?

Thank you.

Comment: I just did a quick google and found this. "for plain WebSockets ws:// you will use port 8000 and for secured connections wss:// port 8443. "

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For plain WebSockets ws:// you will use port 8000 and for secured connections wss:// port 8443.  And if you're looking for a good article on the subject take a look at https://www.openshift.com/blogs/paas-websockets.

Comment: Thank you for your helped. I now have web socket access.